# Trying to Convert Laravel http::post request to PostMan

Tags: laravel, curl, request, http-post, postman

I have an application I'm working on and there's a post request in Laravel that I'm trying to emulate in Postman, but it's just not working.

```php
$response = Http::post('http://third-party-api.com/login', [
    'username'  =>  'username',
    'password'  =>  'password',
]);
```

[image: Postman screenshot]

When I try what I believe to be the same request in Postman, it just tells me the username or password is incorrect.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with `x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: I did and it didn't work either. I just started stabbing in the dark just now and got it to work by trying raw/JSON. I'd love to know why that worked though.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by just randomly trying different things. If anyone knows why this works, I'd love to know.

[image]